# the nth power Logarithmic Integral

Tags: analysis, asymptotics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bounding the integral $\int_{2}^{x} \frac{\mathrm dt}{\log^{n}{t}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7793/bounding-the-integral-int-2x-frac-mathrm-dt-lognt)

So I want to show that $$\int_2^x \frac{1}{\log^n(t)}\mathrm dt=O\left(\frac{x}{\log^n(x)}\right)$$, and someone suggests that I could split the integral into two parts:
$$\int_2^{\sqrt{x}} \frac{1}{\log^n(t)}\mathrm dt+\int_{\sqrt{x}}^x \frac{1}{\log^n(t)}\mathrm dt$$, and why that immediately produces the right error term $O\left(\frac{x}{\log^n(x)}\right)$?

Comment: Both integrals are "small."

Comment: You've seen [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7793) right?